# Magento REST API Payment Method Aditional Information

Tags: php, magento-2.0, payment-methods, rest-api, magento-community

I'm creating orders via REST. When placing the order, I'm invoking this:

**$base_url/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts//order**

When using the 'checkmo' payment method it goes without issues, but when using other payment methods like Credit Card (using Braintree) it asks for additional information. Here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136295/magento-rest-api-pass-additional-payment-method-details I have the additional info for Credit Card Payment, but I would like to know where in the whole Magento docs can I find the additional information for other payment methods such as PayPal, Debit Card, etc.